# White space in XmlElement in C# .Net

Tags: c#, xml

`XmlElement child = doc.CreateElement(element);`

Where `doc` is an object of `XmlDocument`. When the code executes the above line with `element=Tom and Jerry`, I get the following error:

`The '  ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.`

What should I do to include `' '` in XmlDocument? I **can not** replace it with anything else.

What are the other characters which XML element does not support for **name** ?

Comment: better to ask what _is_ allowed in a name. alfanum, '_' and '-'

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you want an element with the *value*  "Tom and Jerry", which is fine.

It is part of the XML syntax that you cannot have a space in the *name* of an element or attribute.

A possible method:

```
XmlElement child = doc.CreateElement("cartoon");
child.InnerText = "Tom and Jerry";
```

which produces

```
<cartoon>Tom and Jerry</cartoon>
```

Aside, consider XDocument when you can. Much easier than XmlDocument.

```
XElement child = new XElement("cartoon", "Tom and Jerry");
```

Comment: Was there any mistake in my question ?

Comment: Click the edit-timestamp and you'll see I changed 'while' to 'white'

Answer (score 4):

It seems your XML **element name** contains spaces...

This is illegal:

```
<tom and jerry>hi</tom and jerry>
```

Must be this:

```
<tomandjerry>hi</tomandjerry>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can make the element like this:

```
<element name='Tom and Jerry' />
```

But if you need to store some data for this cartoon and have access to it by cartoon name:

```
<element name='Tom and Jerry'>some data</element>
```