# How to insert a whitespace character in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am creating an Xml XDocument. When i try to insert a string which contains alphabets, whitespaces, special Characters and numbers. It gives an error at runtime.

```
The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.
```

How can i insert such type of string. Is there any other way to insert this type of string.

Code i am Using:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                   new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
                   new XElement("Mail"));
var template = @"To MOM 
            13, AD1
            tr y
            fghdh, Madhya Pradesh, India 

            Dear Ram,
                  We would like to appoint you for new job";
XElement varXElement = new XElement("studentName", template);
xDoc.Element("Mail").Add(varXElement);
xDoc.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: show us your code you are using

Comment: Your posted code snippet wouldn't compile.  I changed the first line to `XDocument xDoc = ...`, and changed the `varXElement` lines to `var XElement = new XElement("studentNAme", template);` and `xDoc.Element("Mail").Add(varXElement);` and it ran just fine, so something else is going.

Comment: I am afraid but i am still not able to run it. It will compile properly no doubt but when u will try to save it giving filepath = "C:\\doc.xml" it will give you the exception of whitespace characters.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi - I'm able to save it just fine.  However, if you're still having issues, change your save command to this and see if it works:  `xDoc.SaveXml(filePath, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do something like this

```
<some text some>ABAC</some text some>
```

Then its illegal in xml grammar.
If you want to achieve something like this then you have to use attributes

```
<node name ="some text some">ABAC</node >
```

But it's very hard to guess from your question what is your problem.

Comment: Thanx for all of your answers but i came to know that i was doing the same silly mistake which @Anand told above.

Answer (score 1):

> The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.

As the error states you may not put a space in a xml element name.

more info can be found here:

[White space in XmlElement in C# .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226831/white-space-in-xmlelement-in-c-sharp-net)

[Can I create an element with forward slash as part of the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000160/hexadecimal-value-0x20-cannot-be-included-in-a-name)

Comment: So how can i add something like that in XML, is there any way to do it.

Comment: names may not contain spaces. you could use underscores or somthing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you - the following code snippet works for me (need to run VS as administrator to save to the root of C:):

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
                   new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
                   new XElement("Mail"));
            var template = @"To MOM 
            13, AD1
            tr y
            fghdh, Madhya Pradesh, India 

            Dear Ram,
                  We would like to appoint you for new job";
            XElement varXElement = new XElement("studentName", template);
            xDoc.Element("Mail").Add(varXElement);
            xDoc.Save("C:\\doc.xml");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Mail>
  <studentName>To MOM 
            13, AD1
            tr y
            fghdh, Madhya Pradesh, India 

            Dear Ram,
                  We would like to appoint you for new job</studentName>
</Mail>
```

This was with VS 2012 Premium on a Win7 64-bit machine.